# Which Black Fedora fits Chabad?

Tags: minhag, product-recommendation, chabad, black-hats

Recently I've decided that I want to start wearing a double covering for when I daven. I believe that it would thus be best that I get myself a black fedora, however I don't know which to get.

Are there any specific rules as to what I should or shouldn't wear as to not insult people?

(I'm somewhat affiliated with Chabad if that helps)

Comment: Insulting one’s self would be top priority; IOW don’t wear too big/small a size or a pink-speckled unicorn’s top-hat. Other than such considerations I don’t think there are any “specific rules” in terms of *halachah*. IAE, your sensitivity is inspiring.

Comment: @Oliver Who said anything about halacha? This is completely societal, as such pay attention to the what the people are wearing in the society you are hoping to associate with. Ask people in that community whom you trust. It's astounding how small details will determine if a hat is accepted or ridiculed.

Comment: @user6591 My bad, I assumed this q here on MY.SE had something to do with Judaism.

Comment: @Oliver :) Jewish societal norms are Judaism too. Next you'll say white shirts have no source in halacha......

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Brayden! Please take a look at our [tour] for some useful information about the site. As others have alluded to before, this site is meant specifically for questions about the Jewish *religion*, not just Jewish *culture*.

Comment: @user6591 White shirts *don't* have any source in halacha. Or was that a joke that went over my head?

Comment: @DonielF Of course that was a joke. But there are many Jewish societies that put importance on them. That was my point. Asking random people on the internet, most of whom I would guess don't wear white shirts and black hats, which ones to buy doesn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to find some rabbi or neighbors you trust and ask them what sort of hat they buy, and where they buy it. If you want to blend in, that is.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to dress consistently which means to not mix different styles of different groups. You can learn what this means by speaking to your Rabbi but here are some examples.

Each group has its own style for every cloth, for example, a black hat doesn't fit shorts or colored shirt, and a baseball cap doesn't fit a long black coat, and a Sthreiml doesn't fit a short coat.

So observe closely and choose one authentic style for everything, including socks and shoes and tie and shirt and coat AND the hat.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any hat which is a specifically a chabad hat and no style of hat which will result in insulting anyone. There are Lubavitchers that wear other styles including ones that wear streimls. That being said many wear a fedora that is similar to the one that the Rebbe wore and you can google pictures of this. You can also visit a frum hat store and ask them to advise you on style.

Another important point here is that clothing is an external expression and not the defining thing which makes someone a chabad chossid. What type of hat you should wear and if you should wear a hat is something I strongly believe you should speak to a mashpia (spiritual mentor) about. Hope this helps and best of success.